# Group by count zero rows not displaying

Tags: sql

I want to count the amount of rows of every `componistId`. When I run the following SQL statement it works fine:

```
SELECT C.componistId, COUNT(*)
FROM Componist C LEFT JOIN Stuk S ON S.componistId = C.componistId
GROUP BY C.componistId
```

Now I want only the rows where `stukNrOrigineel` is null

```
SELECT C.componistId, COUNT(*)
FROM Componist C LEFT JOIN Stuk S ON S.componistId = C.componistId
WHERE S.stuknrOrigineel IS NULL
GROUP BY C.componistId
```

But when I do this, all the rows with a result of 0 disappear. Only the rows with at least 1 row are displayed. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the condition in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT C.componistId, COUNT(C.componistId)
FROM Componist C LEFT JOIN
     Stuk S
     ON S.componistId = C.componistId AND
        S.stuknrOrigineel IS NULL
GROUP BY C.componistId;
```

Note:  I changed the `COUNT()` to count from the second table.  This is normally what you want when combining `LEFT JOIN` with `COUNT()`.

On some databases, I think the above might not quite work as expected (the question is whether the condition on `S` is evaluated before or after the `LEFT JOIN`).  This should always work:

```
SELECT C.componistId, COUNT(s.componistId)
FROM Componist C LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT S.* FROM Stuk S WHERE S.stuknrOrigineel IS NULL
     ) s
     ON S.componistId = C.componistId AND
GROUP BY C.componistId;
```

Another generic solution is move the condition into the aggregation function:

```
SELECT C.componistId, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN S.stuknrOrigineel IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM Componist C LEFT JOIN
     Stuk S
     ON S.componistId = C.componistId 
GROUP BY C.componistId;
```

Comment: I tried this but then it says it has 1 row at the rows where the result is null while it should be 0

Comment: @Sjoerd . . . You fix that by fixing the argument to `COUNT()`, as in the edited version of the question.

Comment: The first one isn't working but the second one is. Do you know why? I'm making this for school and I havent learned that second method so I think it should be possible in with your first method too somehow.

Comment: the second method isn't working for me either. It says the same as in the first example, 1 row while it has 0. I deleted the 'AND' at the end of the join by the way.

Comment: @Sjoerd . . . It should be counting from the second table `s`, rather than the first table `c`.